# Triggers dividing amount using count not working as expected

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, count

Am trying to add new data to payments table, it should devide the amount by total users
and only add new data entered into the bills table.
However it simply adds them all each time rather than the new data.

Can anyone help me please?

```
    DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `newPayment` 
AFTER INSERT ON `bills`
FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO payments (name, bill, DueDate, Value)
SELECT users.name, bills.Company, bills.billDueDate, bills.Amount/(SELECT COUNT(name) FROM users)
FROM bills, users
WHERE bills.Company=bills.Company AND users.name=users.name
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why you should not use triggers http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48797/does-trigger-improve-the-performance/48903#48903 ive analysed the code behind MySQL triggers and made an post there the explainment is rewriten in the source code as comments

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting all records from the bills table because you're not referencing **anything** about the row that fired the trigger.

Inside an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, there's an alias called `NEW` that references the row that was just inserted.  Presumably you mean to do something like this:

```
WHERE bills.Company=NEW.Company
```

This would select the rows in 'bills' the company is the same as the company in the row you just inserted.

However, I have no idea where "users" figures in, though expect you intend to select from bills `JOIN` users `ON` some kind of criteria.

Comment: Oh thanks mate, users is another table, data itself passes as expected apart from the issue, a good friend of mine suggested its bad practice and should use procedure using tmp tables.